# Ipad mini 4 won't turn on

Tags: ios, ipad

I just got my ipad mini 4 for christmas. It has been working perfectly fine until this morning the battery was completely dead so I wen't to charge it and realized that it wasn't coming on. When I press the power button, the apple sign appears then the screen returns to being black. What is the issue? Is my battery gone?

Comment: Are you using the official apple charger and lighting cable that came with it originally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might just be completely dead right now, or the software is freaking out. Try plugging it into a computer in recovery mode and see if its goes through.